# How to Search a paragraph in a file using grep and then search a specific word from the paragraph

Tags: string, file, unix, search, grep

I want to search the following paragraph from a file and then display a specific word from the paragraph.
eg.

```
"Documentation can be done using 
MS excel and an eg. of such a file is sample.xls"
```

I want ot search the above paragraph from a file example.log and then want to display only the word "sample.xls"

Is it possible???

Comment: what the keyword did we use to search for the above paragraph? ie, how you differentiate the above paragraph with others?

Comment: say "Documentaion can" (combination of both the words) can be used as a keyword to distinguish the paragraph with others

Comment: so you want the filename along with the extension `.xls` from that particular paragraph only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your grep supports `-P`, perl-regexp parameter then you could simply use the below grep command.

```
$ grep -ozP '(?:.+\n)*.*\bDocumentation can\b.*(?:\n.+)*' file | grep -o '[^ ]\+\.xls\b'
sample.xls
```

First grep is used to fetch the particular paragraph and the next grep is used to fetch the files with a particular extension from that paragraph.

Comment: it is identifying the search string in the different paragraphs as well as from the desired one and returning the same. I wanted the search word to be returned from just the specific paragraph. Well am I goin somewhere worng or is there a different approach too??

Comment: another poitn to be considered is "Documentation can" may not be the starting of a line.It may even occur in middle of the para

Comment: i think there is a blank line between each paragraph. Could you post the sample of how paragraphs look like?

Comment: for eg.
Connection reset error
                at java.net.socketinputstream
Caught an exception for the sample.xls

Comment: for eg.
Connection reset error
                at java.net.socketinputstream
Caught an exception for the sample.xls

(here the differentiating owrd wd be "Connection reset" )